# problem in excluding changing js code parts in jch plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x

i'm using jch plugin to speed up my site. but i have some problems configuring it.

1. there is a piece of inline js code that keeps changing in js file that jch plugin creates. but this part isn't in the code parts that the plugin offers to exclude. and also the module that creates this part of js code, isn't there to exclude. what should i do?
   there are 2 code part offered by jch plg that are similar to these 2 (similar at the beginning of the code)
2. when i enable "Sprite Generator", total page size of my site increases.
    how should i solve this?
3. sometimes the site opens in mobile view on desktop :/  wierrrrrd

my site address: www.farafan-market.com

Comment: Without a preview of the site, we cannot really help. I;d also suggest fiddling around with some of the plugins settings. Having used this plugin many times on various site, I can say that setting it to the maximum caching level will start causing issues.

Comment: u mean i shouldn't put it on "optimum" level??

Comment: I would simply suggest fiddling around with the settings. Also, don't go with the pre-defined settings. Set everything back to default, then enabled each setting one by one and see if everything is ok

Comment: my main problem is the number 1 that i explained. how can i exclude the js code part?

Comment: I'm not sure as I didn't really understand what you meant by it.

Comment: @Lodder when its on "optimum" and i disable for example "search body" feature, when i open my site, there are some errors in console :/

Comment: Conversely to @lodder I've been ok with this plugin and they update it regularly.

Comment: It would help to understand the errors in the console too.  If it is a 403 or a 404 then perhaps something else is interfering.  I have had issues with Admin Tools .htaccess maker blocking it but it's easy to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the JS is inline then perhaps you can override the model to take it into a separate file which may solve your issue with JCH.
2. If the sprite generator makes your site slightly larger that's no issue. Because it reduces the amount of requests so your site should load more quickly - but check!  It has to use a PNG as it needs to be transparent. But PNG is a larger files than JPG. Hence the increased file size.